# Find the volume inside the paraboloid $x^2+4z^2+8y=16$ and on the positive side of xz-plane

Tags: calculus, integration

No answer was given for this question, so wanted to confirm my answer. Steps followed for solving:

V=$4\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{16-4z^2}}(2-\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{z^2}{2})dxdz$

After solving this I got V = $8\pi$. Is this answer correct?

Comment: How about you show your working so that it's easier for us to check?

Comment: I would have integrated along $y$ first. This way, no parasite negative instances of $y$ can occur. eg $V = \int_0^2 2 \cdot \int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{16 - 8y}}{2}} \sqrt{16 - 8y - 4z^2} dz dy$. In other words, you integrate elliptical slices along the $y$ axis.

Comment: @Oliver Roche, should it be 4 times the integral to get you to the answer of $8\pi$ than your current $4\pi$

Comment: @Olivier Roche, should it be 4 times the integral to get you to the answer of $8\pi$ than your current $4\pi$

Comment: @SatishRamanathan The 2 is here to take the negative root of $16 - 8y - 4z^2$ into account.

Comment: @ShivaneeGupta, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates,$ x = rcos\theta$ and $z = \frac{r}{2}sin\theta$ and the Jacobian is $\frac{r}{2}$

$$V = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{4} \frac{(16-r^2)}{8} \frac{r}{2}drd\theta = 8\pi$$

Comment: Hey, I have just started learning calculus..I don't know this method of solving integrals yet. If possible can you tell me good source to learn integration using polar co-ordinates? Also what is wrong in my method of solving this problem?

Comment: The integration is easier in polar coordinates than cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @SatishRamanathan What about the condition $y\geqslant 0$?

Comment: @Olivier Roche, the solid bounded by inverted paraboloid with vertex at y=2 and the positive side of xy plane which is y>0.

Comment: @OlivierRoche,  the 4 is for 2 on x and 2 on z from one side of the axis to the other giving a total of 4

Comment: @SatishRamanathan I didn't understand that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Integral - $$v = 4\int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{16-4z^2} 1/8(16-x^2 +4z^2) \,dx\,dz$$

Answer is $$ {8\pi} $$

below is the Exact solution of the given question -
[image: Exact Solution]